Can I get file descriptor info from a core file by gdb?
I have a core file caused by 'too many open file' in Linux.
I want to know how many fds the program used at crash time and the mapping of fds.
Can I get file descriptor list from that core file?
With gdb or some other tools?

If you have terminal access (directly or remotely) you can use the ulimit -n command to get the descriptor limit.

Yes, current limit is fine. But I found out that someone may have modified the /proc/sys/fs/nr_open file after the crash, so I wanted to determine the number of fds at the time of the crash

I am highly doubtful that the number of open files permitted is recorded in the core dump.

On Linux, core dumps are normally in ELF format.  However, the ELF specification doesn't tell us anything about the content format - only how to identify that it's a core file.
So we need to look at the source of binfmt_elf.c where core files are written.  There's a promising-looking function called fill_files_note(), but on closer reading, it appears to be recording memory-mapped files (including the program and library text), rather than file descriptors.
It appears that no information about open fds is recorded in a Linux core file.  If you believe that useful data could be recorded, you'll need to write the code to do so yourself.

You can just set a breakpoint for the crash and then check /proc/<pid>/fd of your program, you can get the pid from info proc

Only if you can reproduce the crash.  The question is asking about a core dump from a process which crashed and is no longer running.
